# arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here? I have tried various combinations to try and copy an array into variable mmm.  I am trying to learn how to create a 2D array and then run a loop to place init_array into 10 columns.

```
// NSMutableArray *mmm = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 20];
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"cat", @"dog", nil];
NSMutableArray *mmm; //= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];

[mmm arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:kkk];

NSLog(@"Working: %@",[mmm objectAtIndex:3]);
```

thanks...

so this works from the given answer:

```
NSMutableArray *mmm = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 20];
NSMutableArray *kkk = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"cat", @"dog", nil];

[mmm addObjectsFromArray:kkk];

NSLog(@"Working: %@",[mmm objectAtIndex:3]);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` returns a *new* (autoreleased) `NSArray` object. What you want is `addObjectsFromArray:`.

Comment: do I have to "retain" this to use outside of the scope?

Comment: @Kristen Martinson: Object lifetimes aren't really related to scope. You have to retain to keep an object you don't own alive past the draining of the current autorelease pool.

Answer (score 10):

`arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` returns a new NSArray that includes the objects in the receiver followed by the objects in the argument. The code you posted there, with `mmm` unset, will probably just crash since `mmm` doesn't point to an NSArray object. If you had assigned an array to `mmm`, then it would return `(@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"a", @"b", @"cat", @"dog")` — but you don't assign the result to any variable, so it just goes nowhere. You'd have to do something like `NSArray *yetAnotherArray = [mmm arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:kkk]`.

If you have an NSMutableArray and you want to add objects from another array, use `addObjectsFromArray:`.

Comment: Since the other guy was first with the solution, I had to chose him... but you added more info so i gave you a point