# display the contents of  3 xml files in a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, nsarray

in my iphone app programmatically i have created 3 directories on ipnone memory , and moved one  ImageNames.xml(say it has a multiple tags with the same name) file to each of the 3 folders

i know how to parse a ImageNames.xml file and take the contents in the array,,but i need to display the contents of all 3 Array(each array from separate files) in a table view,,how can i do this,,can any one help me,
i tried in the following way

```
for(int intVar=0;intVar<[arrDownloadedDirNames count];intVar++)
    {

[self ImgNamesXMLParser:[arrDownloadedDirNames objectAtIndex:intVar]];//calling  ImageNames.xml xml parser(parameter is the folder names in which xml file exist)

 NSMutableSet *set = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:arrImageNames];
  [set addObjectsFromArray:arrImageNames];

  NSArray *array = [set allObjects];
}
```

But this didnt work,,can any one sujjest me how can i do this? thanx in advance

Comment: a little more specifications, from what you said you done all the hard work already and since you put them in an array you just have to display them as you would any other array of objects sow just google a simple tutorial for uitableview that uses an array and you are done , that is if i understood corectly your problem.

Comment: thanx for ur reply radu,i already know how to load array to table view in my above code in the for loop i am parsing all the image.xml which are in different folders , now i am not getting how to merge all 3 arrays into a single,[self ImgNamesXMLParser:[arrDownloadedDirNames objectAtIndex:intVar]];//calling  ImageNames.xml xml parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make 3 NSArray's from the 3 diffrent XML files and then merge them in a NSMutableArray using the addObjectsFromArray method.

I imagine that arrImageNames is the result array after parsing the xmlfile

```
NSMutableArray* theResultArray =[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int intVar=0;intVar<[arrDownloadedDirNames count];intVar++)
        {

    [self ImgNamesXMLParser:[arrDownloadedDirNames objectAtIndex:intVar]];//calling  ImageNames.xml xml parser(parameter is the folder names in which xml file exist)
    //... ...
      [theResultArray addObjectsFromArray:arrImageNames];    
    }
```

Now theResultArray, should contain the objects from the arrImageName.  Use addObjectsFromArray and the array will ad the objects from the (parameter array to the ones it already has)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you require, nevertheless, did you try using arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray instance method. A related post can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702437/arraybyaddingobjectsfromarray).